# Are sent Facebook message requests deleted if sender account is deactivated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

This situation involves two accounts NOT connected (not yet "friends"), as obviously the message sent is just a "Message Request".

Say a message request was "Sent" but not "Delivered" and sender deactivated account, would the recipient still see it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be deleted.

Yes, recipient will see it when it will deliver to recipient's inbox, and if they click on message request inbox, but they will not able to click on sender's name as sender has deactivated the account, means sender's name will be there without hyperlink. When sender reactivate their account hyperlink will be activated to the name.

Deactivating account will not delete anything. If you deactivate your account:

- You can reactivate whenever you want.
- People can't see your timeline or search for you.
- Some info may remain visible (example: messages you sent).

Answer (score -1):

I have come across this situation recently and I believe that message you sent to unknown (not yet friend) would be in message request section. And if you delete your account (not talking about deactivated account) those messages you have sent disappeared. Even if they had already view it. Don't panic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).